# Generate JSON structure

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to create the following JSON result in my code (C#) as this is how the API that I am using would want the JSON to be, but not able to create it exactly, hence which is why the API returns with errors.

End result:

```
{
  "reportKey" : {
     "key" : "552d20ce-1269-4cb4-a679-0cd51d3e2058"
  }
}
```

In my code, I have

```
var reportKey = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", reportId);
var requestJson = new { reportKey };
```

When I look up the JSON value by serializing this `requestJson` using the `JsonConvert`, it comes up as

```
{ reportKey : { key : "key", value : "CBHJ1234" } }
```

Not the way I want it up above.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? I probably don't want to use `KeyValuePair` here, do I?

Comment: How about use Dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ironically, a `KeyValuePair`, when serialised to JSON, creates two key value pairs because it has two properties `Key` and `Value`.

The easiest way to do this is to not use `KeyValuePair`, and just create an anonymous class yourself:

```
var objectToSerialise = new {
    reportKey = new {
        key = reportId
    }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialise);
```